# formatting numbers in pandas

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

for a pandas.DataFrame: df

```
     min           max          mean
a    0.0  2.300000e+04  6.450098e+02
b    0.0  1.370000e+05  1.651754e+03
c  218.0  1.221550e+10  3.975262e+07
d    1.0  5.060000e+03  2.727708e+02
e    0.0  6.400000e+05  6.560047e+03
```

I would like to format the display such as numbers show in the 
":,.2f" format (that is ##,###.##) and remove the exponents.

I tried: `df.style.format("{:,.2f}")`which gives: `<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x108b86f60>` that i have no idea what to do with. 
Any lead please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this young Pandas apprentice

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format
```