# Pandas DF elts conversion and modification

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm completely new to both pandas and excel management with python.
I've got 2 numpy arrays:

- One with values
- One with %

Each of them forms a matrix of 26*26 which will be written in an excel sheet, in the same file. To simplify, we can take an example of 4*4. This matrix are triangular.
I create a pandas df for each of this matrix, and then replace 0 value by "".

```
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=col)
df = df.astype(str)
df.replace(['0', '0.0'], '', inplace=True)
```

Once it's done, I write it to excel:

```
df.to_excel(df.writer, sheet_name="Name", index=False)
```

I get :

```
f    20    50    100    150
20   val1  val2  val3   val4
50         val5  val6   val7
100              val8   val9
150                     val10
```

EDIT: As you can see, I don't want to fill cells with 0 values.

The problem is that the values are stored as text in excel; and not as numeric values (floats). I've tried this command before saving the writer, but it didn't change anything:

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

How can I fix this?

The second question is about the values: some of them have far too many digits (in the % sheets). One quick example:
    0.1586111111111111

How can I reduce this to 0.1586?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: For second question you can read  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46773691/4819376).

Comment: Probably my bad, but it doesn't change anything :/