# Minimal decimal number in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, decimal

I'm trying to make a dataframe in pandas where all columns have at least 6 decimals. I've tried splitting the decimal numbers on their . and look at the decimal length accordingly. There must be an easier way. How do I do this?

Comment: have a look there: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46773603/14333932

Comment: Hi, thank you, initially I wanted to delete all columns with less than 6 decimals but this works too!